# warm start AMPL API

Tags: optimization, ampl

I am using AMPL API in MATLAB and trying to set initial value for variables.

```
set BUS := {1 2};
set Tiem := { 1 2 3};
var Pcharge  {BUS , Time};
```

I am wondering in AMPL API how I can give a matrix like Z as an initial solving point to the solver

```
Z = [ 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6];
```

in the ampl api documentation it is said that I can do this like

```
ampl.eval('var x;');
x = ampl.getVariable('x');
x.setValue(4);
```

so when I do the same I get this error:

```
Error using VariableBase/setValue (line 296)
No method 'setValue' with matching signature found for class 'com.ampl.Variable'.

Error in Entity/subsref (line 73)
                builtin('subsref',self,key);
```

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this please?

Thanks.